# Eclipse Mars is not saving preferences

Tags: java, eclipse

Ctrl+Space is not showing proposals. e.g sysout or arr. is not working. I tried to restore default from Content Assist-> Advanced.

But, the changes which I make does not get saved and it reverts back to the original settings in preferences. Has anyone encountered this before? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help? If it did, make sure to accept it with the checkmark. If you have more questions, feel free to ask. I am happy to help! :-)

Comment: Had similar problem with regard to formatter preferences for comments on Eclipse 4.7.1 Oxygen.1, but elsewhere a remark about enabling Preference recording via Oomph seems to have solved this.  1) It is bad that user interface does not warn you to set Oomph when you Apply or Apply and Close.  2) Still formatting my comments even though I have turned off formatting online whitespace between code and comments (but that is a separate issue).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually kind of common in eclipse.

Although this link doesn't describe the exact symptoms you have stated, the solution it proposes may be able to solve your issue:

http://mschrag.blogspot.co.nz/2009/01/open-type-cant-find-your-class.html

> - Quit Eclipse
> - Go to workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core
> - Remove *.index and savedIndexNames.txt
> - Restart Eclipse and search Ctrl+T for the offending type. The indexes will be rebuilt.

Try doing that. If it still doesn't work, try to delete the class itself, and re make it. Just copy and paste. Again, you mentioned the default preferences:

```
Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced
```

The [Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist-advanced.htm) tells to restore:

> Select the proposal kinds contained in the **'default' content assist list**:
>
> - Other Java Proposals,
> - SWT Template Proposals,
> - Template Proposals,
> - Type Proposals

Now, also go in here:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters
```

And make sure that you didn't filter out random stuff that you don't want to filter out. Also try to just disable everything there.

Let me know if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Eclipse Neon.
It may be linked to Code Recommenders because only the "**Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)**" item will be saved when checked.

[image: Java Proposals (Code Recommenders) checked]

But when you uncheck this item it will allow you to save some other items. I don't understand why but some items will still remained unsaved.

[image: Java Proposals (Code Recommenders) unchecked]